# avcodec_receive_packet() doesn't see the output

Tags: ios, encoding, ffmpeg, avcodec

I'm trying to create a converter which will make a video out of set of images. Everything is at its place, `AVFormatContext`, `AVCodecContext`, `AVCodec`. I'm creating YUV AVFrame out of UIImage and send it to encoder by `avcodec_send_frame()` method. Everything goes fine until I'm trying to get `AVPacket` with method `avcodec_receive_packet()`. Every time it returns -53 which means - `output is not available in the current state - user must try to send input`. As I said, I'm sending an input before I'm trying to get something and sending is successful.

Here's my code:

Init ffmpeg entities:

```
- (BOOL)setupForConvert:(DummyFVPVideoFile *)videoFile outputPath:(NSString *)path
{
    if (!videoFile) {
        [self.delegate convertationFailed:@"VideoFile is nil!"];
        return NO;
    }
    currentVideoFile = videoFile;
    outputPath = path;
    BOOL success = NO;

    success = [self initFormatCtxAndCodecs:path];
    if (!success) {
        return NO;
    }

    success = [self addCameraStreams:videoFile];
    if (!success) {
        return NO;
    }

    success = [self openIOContext:path];
    if (!success) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)initFormatCtxAndCodecs:(NSString *)path
{
    //AVOutputFormat *fmt = av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL);
    int ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&pFormatCtx, NULL, NULL, [path UTF8String]);
    if (ret < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create output context");
        return NO;
    }

    //encoder codec init
    pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!pCodec) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't find a encoder codec!");
        return NO;
    }

    pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
    if (!pCodecCtx) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't alloc encoder codec context!");
        return NO;
    }

    pCodecCtx->codec_tag = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    pCodecCtx->bit_rate = 400000;
    pCodecCtx->width = currentVideoFile.size.width;
    pCodecCtx->height = currentVideoFile.size.height;
    pCodecCtx->time_base = (AVRational){1, (int)currentVideoFile.framerate};
    pCodecCtx->framerate = (AVRational){(int)currentVideoFile.framerate, 1};
    pCodecCtx->gop_size = 10;
    pCodecCtx->max_b_frames = 1;
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't open the encoder codec!");
        return NO;
    }

    pPacket = av_packet_alloc();

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)addCameraStreams:(DummyFVPVideoFile *)videoFile
{
    AVCodecParameters *params = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    if (!params) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't allocate codec parameters!");
        return NO;
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_from_context(params, pCodecCtx) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't copy parameters from context!");
        return NO;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < videoFile.idCameras.count - 1; i++)
    {
        NSString *path = [videoFile.url URLByAppendingPathComponent:videoFile.idCameras[i]].path;
        AVStream *stream = avformat_new_stream(pFormatCtx, pCodec);
        if (!stream) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't alloc stream!");
            return NO;
        }

        if (avcodec_parameters_copy(stream->codecpar, params) < 0) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't copy parameters into stream!");
            return NO;
        }

        stream->avg_frame_rate.num = videoFile.framerate;
        stream->avg_frame_rate.den = 1;
        stream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;    //some silly workaround
        stream->index = i;
        streams[path] = [[VideoStream alloc] initWithStream:stream];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)openIOContext:(NSString *)path
{
    AVIOContext *ioCtx = nil;
    if (avio_open(&ioCtx, [path UTF8String], AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    pFormatCtx->pb = ioCtx;

    return YES;
}
```

And here's convertation process:

```
- (void)launchConvert:(DummyFVPVideoFile *)videoFile
{
    BOOL convertInProgress = YES;
    unsigned int frameCount = 1;
    unsigned long pts = 0;
    BOOL success = NO;

    success = [self writeHeader];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't write header!");
        return;
    }

    AVRational defaultTimeBase;
    defaultTimeBase.num = 1;
    defaultTimeBase.den = videoFile.framerate;
    AVRational streamTimeBase = streams.allValues.firstObject.stream->time_base;

    while (convertInProgress)
    {
        pts += av_rescale_q(1, defaultTimeBase, streamTimeBase);
        for (NSString *path in streams.allKeys)
        {
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%u.jpg", path, frameCount]];
            AVPacket *pkt = [self getAVPacket:img withPts:pts];
            if (!pkt->data) {   continue;   }
            pkt->stream_index = streams[path].stream->index;
            //check all settings of pkt

            if (![self writePacket:pkt]) {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't write packet!");
                convertInProgress = NO;
                break;
            }
        }

        frameCount++;
    }

    success = [self writeTrailer];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't write trailer!");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Convertation finished!");
    //delegate convertationFinished method
}

- (BOOL)writeHeader
{
    if (avformat_write_header(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)writePacket:(AVPacket *)pkt
{
    if (av_interleaved_write_frame(pFormatCtx, pkt) != 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)writeTrailer
{
    if (av_write_trailer(pFormatCtx) != 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


/**
 This method will create AVPacket out of UIImage.

 @return AVPacket
 */
- (AVPacket *)getAVPacket:(UIImage *)img withPts:(unsigned long)pts
{
    if (!img) {
        NSLog(@"imgData is nil!");
        return nil;
    }
    uint8_t *imgData = [self getPixelDataFromImage:img];

    AVFrame *frame_yuv = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_yuv) {
        NSLog(@"frame_yuv is nil!");
        return nil;
    }
    frame_yuv->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame_yuv->width = (int)img.size.width;
    frame_yuv->height = (int)img.size.height;

    int ret = av_image_alloc(frame_yuv->data,
                               frame_yuv->linesize,
                               frame_yuv->width,
                               frame_yuv->height,
                               frame_yuv->format,
                               32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't alloc yuv frame!");
        return nil;
    }

    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = nil;
    sws_ctx = sws_getContext((int)img.size.width, (int)img.size.height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                             (int)img.size.width, (int)img.size.height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                             0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    const uint8_t *scaleData[1] = { imgData };
    int inLineSize[1] = { 4 * img.size.width };
    sws_scale(sws_ctx, scaleData, inLineSize, 0, (int)img.size.height, frame_yuv->data, frame_yuv->linesize);

    frame_yuv->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I;
    frame_yuv->pts = pCodecCtx->frame_number;

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(pCodecCtx, frame_yuv);   //every time everything is fine
    if (ret != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't send yuv frame!");
        return nil;
    }

    av_init_packet(pPacket);
    pPacket->dts = pPacket->pts = pts;
    do {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(pCodecCtx, pPacket);   //every time -35 error
        NSLog(@"ret = %d", ret);
        if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            NSLog(@"AVERROR_EOF!");
        } else if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
            NSLog(@"AVERROR(EAGAIN)");
        } else if (ret == AVERROR(EINVAL)) {
            NSLog(@"AVERROR(EINVAL)");
        }
        if (ret != 0) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't receive packet!");
            //return nil;
        }
    } while ( ret == 0 );

    free(imgData);
    av_packet_unref(pPacket);
    av_packet_free(pPacket);
    av_frame_unref(&frame_yuv);
    av_frame_free(&frame_yuv);
    //perform other clean up and test dat shit

    return pPacket;
}
```

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There may be two reasons.

1. According to on of the documents of `FFmpeg` you may need to feed more then one packet to `avcodec_send_frame()` to receive packet return successful.
2. I cannot confirm that you allocated enough sized buffer for `pPacket`. The functions `av_packet_alloc()` and `av_init_packet()` won't allocate any buffer but latter sets it to NULL instead. So allocation must be done after init. Somewhere you should allocate buffer either manually or with `av_new_packet(pPacket, SIZE)`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your effort. About your suggestions: 1) I tried to feed buffer with avcodec_send_frame(). But it didn't much of an impact. In fact, I tried to feed null frame which signals for EOF, avcodec_receive_packet() saw that perfectly. But I really can't understand where I went wrong with AVFrame initialization.                     2) That might be an idea, BUT, I saw lots of encoding examples, couple of them from FFMpeg distributors themselves, and they all send the packet with NULL buffer in that.

Comment: Yes you were right about packet allocation, may bad (as documentation says https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga5b8eff59cf259747cf0b31563e38ded6 .

Comment: Also I found that you allocate `sws_getContext` every time `getAVPacket` function called. If sizes are constant you should call it only once and keep the sws_ctx pointer for later use or call `sws_freeContext` before calling next time.
I suspect your `frame` might have some issues, it seems the error code comes from the codec itself. Please check my tested scaling functions (I used on some project) with yours (ignore the LOGFs): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DRDgNhKpQv/

Comment: That's a good point about context allocation, I didn't notice it, thank you for bringing it into my attention. Also thanks for your code, I'll check it out, hopefully today. And yeah, it seems like a logic conclusion that something is wrong with my frame, BUT I found couple of encode examples from FFMpeg distributors and they were using "dummy" frame (created pixel through array). I copied that dummy frame and I still have same issues :( I guess this is could be a bug of FFMpeg itself.

Comment: I see, so I assume you tried this with `AV_CODEC_ID_H264`: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_video_8c-example.html#a9 and still no luck? if that's the case, can you confirm your FFmpeg setup with libx264 configured and installed ?